# How to distinguish FileFilter and FilenameFilter in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, lambda

I would like to list files of certain types and wrote:

```
File[] imageFiles = srcDir.listFiles({ File file ->
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1ldpi.png") ||
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1mdpi.png") ||
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1hdpi.png") ||
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1xhdpi.png") ||
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1xxhdpi.png") ||
            file().name.endsWith("Artboard1xxxhdpi.png")
        })
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
> Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#listFiles.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class CLOSURENAME] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface java.io.FileFilter]
    [interface java.io.FilenameFilter]
```

How to hint Groovy, what to choose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
File[] imageFiles = srcDir.listFiles({ File file ->
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1ldpi.png") ||
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1mdpi.png") ||
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1hdpi.png") ||
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1xhdpi.png") ||
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1xxhdpi.png") ||
    file.name.endsWith("Artboard1xxxhdpi.png")
} as FileFilter)
```

Answer (score 5):

This also should work, DRY ;)

```
File[] imageFiles = srcDir.listFiles({ File file ->
   [
      "Artboard1ldpi.png",
      "Artboard1ldpi.png",
      "Artboard1mdpi.png",
      "Artboard1hdpi.png",
      "Artboard1xhdpi.png",
      "Artboard1xxhdpi.png",
      "Artboard1xxxhdpi.png",
   ].any { file.name.endsWith(it) }
} as FileFilter)
```